# Couldn't set my Java version right for flutter on mac

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am planning to install flutter on my mac, but have troble to install it. with error

`Unable to find bundled Java version.` i sourced all possible solutions i could for stack over flow but no luck.

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/075NP.png)

any help is appreciated. thanks.

i tried below: but no luck because i don't have jre in android studio instead i have jbr. i am using Android studio eletric eel

cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
flutter doctor -v
reference: my android is working fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUJMr.png)

Comment: Kindly update your question properly with [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far

Comment: Please add code snippet for better understanding of problem to resolve the problem